# Facebook Cover Picture Comment Disabling

Tags: facebook, facebook-profile, facebook-comments

How do I disable comment on my Facebook cover picture

Comment: Does the suggested answer helped you?

Answer (score 1):

## You can't.

#### References:

1. [The turn off comments is only available in groups](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/community/question/?id=127753290973337&answer_id=130978257317507&rdrhc):

   > There is no way to turn off commenting for posts on your Business Page. This feature is only available for Groups. You can turn off the ability for other people posting to your Page
2. [The current Facebook profile and cover picture would always be public](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10152295255282184):

   > You can hide all your profile pictures except the current one, it is public and anyone can see it.
3. [You can't disable comments for everyone on your public profile info](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=followers&section=public_profile_media&view):

   > **Public Profile Info**
   >
   > Who can like or comment on your public profile pictures and other profile info?
   >
   > - Public
   > - Friends of Friends
   > - Friends